# How do I open Sencha Docs examples in Architect?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I downloaded the examples shown in Sencha Docs, e.g. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/example/maps, and installed Architect on my Windows computer.

I want to modify the examples shown here: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/index.html

inside Architect but the program is asking for an .xds or .xda file. How do I generate this file type so I can use a WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 1):

The application you are trying to import is a Sencha Touch project (not an Architect one), so there's no way to import it.

Comment: Is there a way to port/convert it?

Comment: The only way is: Recreate components by using sencha architect toolbox + Recreate functions by using sencha architect inspector + Adding external resources to it. No programmatical way to convert, at least for now